# How to use code written in `std` in `no_std` during runtime?

Tags: pallet, rust, json

I have a piece of code written in `std`, and it is bypassing/not-included in runtime as it should work but I want to use it in runtime environment, is there a way to use it. As the code written in `std` will not compile with native substrate `no_std` build.

Basically code is parsing a json and storing its key value in a `StorageMap` which we will get during runtime and it is a dynamic value which will change after every era.

Piece of code is as follows:

```
#[pallet::call]
impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    #[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1))]
    pub fn esg_score(origin: OriginFor<T>, json_data: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResult {
        let signer = ensure_signed(origin)?;
        #[cfg(feature = "std")]
        let parseAndStoreData = |jsonStr: &str| {
            let parsed: ListOfScores = serde_json::from_str(jsonStr).unwrap()
            for item in parsed.0 {
                <GetScore::<T>>::insert(item.account.clone(), item.score);
            }
                                
            #[cfg(feature = "std")]
            parseAndStoreEsgData(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&json_data[..])[..]);         
            Self::deposit_event(Event::Stored(json_data, signer.clone()));
            Ok(())
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad direction, as even if you get this to work, your native and wasm runtime will produce different state root, and therefore your blockchain consensus will break. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

Check my previous answer: [Compiled code withe #[cfg(feature = "std")] and facing issues while setting up staging environment](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4995/compiled-code-withe-cfgfeature-std-and-facing-issues-while-setting-up-s)

---

You should transform that code/lib to `no_std`.

For your example, `String` is a `Vec` actually. You should use the `Vec<u8>` directly.

If you want to play with JSON object, I think there are some crates that provide a `json::from_bytes(&json_data)` method.

- [`serde_json` no-std support](https://github.com/serde-rs/json#no-std-support)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it is generally heavily discouraged to use JSON in a substrate runtime, and one should use SCALE instead. See e.g. [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3370/2673).

Comment: Yep, thanks. But if he wants to use JSON anyway. Anyway, this is just an example. I think 'how to deal with the bytes object in Substrate' would be another question. It's a little bit off-topic.